# Remove the decimal point after 100k rep

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, user-interface, flair

As Jon Skeet reaches 1000 bronze badges, the reputation line in flair is not going to fit there any more.

I suggest reducing the precision as you reach 100k (just like what happens with 10k users) by removing the decimal point altogether and rounding to the nearest "k" boundary, thus displaying 100.2k as 100k.

Comment: You should tag this `Jon-Skeet` because it's only a Jon Skeet problem ;)

Comment: Not really. I'm sure we'll have a few 100k users in a few months.

Comment: Before they reach 100k, Jon will have 1000. Then it is a Skeet problem again.

Comment: What about 1 million rep? And 10mill rep etc. I think your not thinking about a scaling solution. But just patching up the problem as it appears.

Comment: 1340K can be shown as 1.34M. We have a few years to reach 1M.

Comment: @Mehrdad: we need some years, but Jon doesn't!

Comment: @Mehrdad: you are no fun anymore!

Comment: Soon-to-be-true Jon Skeet fact: Jon Skeets flair is 3px wider than everyone elses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just dropping the decimal point is enough. The field is enough to hold 4 letters. With `margin-left: -2px;` in the badges counts its enough for a correction when somebody reaches more than 999. I think that you can't scale more than that with a clean interface. Maybe don't show the bronze badges when you are over 9999 silver badges?

[image: TheTAXI 18M]

[image: TheTAXI 555k]

[image: TheTAXI 555k and a lot of badges]

Comment: What colour are Bronco badges?

Comment: Could show bronze badges as "k" too.

Comment: TheTAXI? Who is that person?

Comment: @Mehrdad: that's a good sugestion toom but realistically, I don't think it will be a problem for at least a few years that Jon Skeet reaches thousands of gold badges.

Comment: Loving TheTAXI.

Comment: You should have changed TheTAXI's gravatar too. :)

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps a better solution to it all (and avoid scaling issues in the future) is just to drop the badge counts to the next line underneath the rep, giving the rep and the badge counts more room to grow outwards.

Comment: Especially for those who will eventually get 3-digit numbers for all three types of badges. This would probably keep that particular block from feeling as crowded. (not my problem... yet)

Comment: It'll be a *very* long time before I'm into triple-digits for gold badges - but quite soon it'll be 2/3/4, so still 9 digits.

Answer (score 5):

Just use three significant figures for everything, including badges.

- 1
- 10
- 100
- 1.00k
- 10.0k
- 100k
- 1.00M
- 10.0M
- 100M

etc.

Comment: that is essentially what we do, I agree