# Why doesn't the flair display decimal points here?

Tags: support, flair, combined-flair

https://stackexchange.com/users/1529456/user67275?tab=flair

My flair displays my total reputation as '10k'.

When I sum up the reputations of relevant (>= 200) SE sites, it is 10,176.
Then it should display it as 10.1k according to [Remove the decimal point after 100k rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23420/remove-the-decimal-point-after-100k-rep).

The above post says it displays three significant digits.

Why is it different from mine? Has the policy changed?

Comment: Are those [scores real](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141628/why-is-my-total-reputation-less-than-my-monthly-reputation)?

Comment: If I run `[...document.querySelectorAll('.account-stat:nth-child(3) span.account-number')].reduce((sum, element) => {const value = +element.innerText.replaceAll(/,/g, ''); return sum += (value >= 200 ? value : 0);}, 0)` on the accounts sub-tab it yields `10234`. Should some other values be excluded - e.g. MetaSE, area 51?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum Yes, the 10,176 is my real reputation just before posting this question.